# Infloblox: Uninstall without uninstallation code

Tags: security

I'm trying to uninstall BloxOne Endpoint. Is there a way to uninstall this without the code?

[image: img]

Comment: Ask your IT department. The code is to prevent unauthorised removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to go to the directory folder and delete the files in there